# What's wrong with my program? About the Ascii 13[Enter]

Tags: vb6

We had an activity last time. It  was converting my classmate's python code to vb... This was my final code and it's running.

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
    curyear = Int(2013)
    a = Int((curyear - txtInput.Text) Mod 12)



        txtInput.Text = " "
        If (a = 9) Or (a = -3) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Snake"
        ElseIf (a = 8) Or (a = -4) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Dragon"
        ElseIf (a = 7) Or (a = -5) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Rabbit"
        ElseIf (a = 6) Or (a = -6) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Tiger"
        ElseIf (a = 5) Or (a = -7) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Ox"
        ElseIf (a = 4) Or (a = -8) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Rat"
        ElseIf (a = 3) Or (a = -9) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Pig"
        ElseIf (a = 2) Or (a = -10) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Dog"
        ElseIf (a = 1) Or (a = -11) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Rooster"
        ElseIf (a = 0) Or (a = -2) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Monkey"
        ElseIf (a = 11) Or (a = -1) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Sheep"
        ElseIf (a = 12) Or (a = 0) Then
            txtOutput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is Horse"
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Our professor told me about other use of ascii 13/ enter... i can't understand him well. What do you think is wrong with my code? It is running but he said my code is wrong.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that unless you set `KeyAscii` to 0, it will be handled by the text box which, depending on the `Multiline` property will be interpreted as a new line. I would ask them for clarification.

Comment: You've hardcoded the current year. Maybe that's an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to clean up your code a bit.

- Instead of using all those Else If statement, a better approach is to
  use Select Case.
- You don't have to Int() on your 3rd or 4th line. It's already an
  Integer.
- You also don't have to repeat the string of "You zodiac sign is ".
  Just use it once.
- And as Deanna said, you need to remove the ASCII 13 from your textbox
  input.

So, the new code:

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   Dim ZodiacAnimal As String
   If KeyAscii = 13 Then
      curyear = 2013
      a = (curyear - txtInput.Text) Mod 12
      Select Case a
         Case 9, -3
            ZodiacAnimal = "Snake"
         Case 8, -4
            ZodiacAnimal = "Dragon"
         Case 7, -5
            ZodiacAnimal = "Rabbit"
         Case 6, -6
            ZodiacAnimal = "Tiger"
         Case 5, -7
            ZodiacAnimal = "Ox"
         Case 4, -8
            ZodiacAnimal = "Rat"
         Case 3, -9
            ZodiacAnimal = "Pig"
         Case 2, -10
            ZodiacAnimal = "Dog"
         Case 1, -11
            ZodiacAnimal = "Rooster"
         Case 0, -2
            ZodiacAnimal = "Monkey"
         Case 11, -1
            ZodiacAnimal = "Sheep"
         Case 12, 0
            ZodiacAnimal = "Horse"
      End Select
      txtInput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is " & ZodiacAnimal
      KeyAscii to 0
   End If
End Sub
```

Now, a couple other problems I see.

- You have the year hard coded. The zodiac is about the year you were born, and doesn't have anything to do with the current year.
- You have 0 listed twice.

Now, this may be too advanced for you, but here's how I would have coded it:

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   Dim ZodiacAnimal() As String
   If KeyAscii = 13 Then
      ZodiacAnimal = Split("Monkey,Rooster,Dog,Pig,Rat,Ox,Tiger,Rabbit,Dragon,Snake,Horse,Goat", ",")
      txtInput.Text = "Your zodiac sign is " & ZodiacAnimal(Y Mod 12) 
      KeyAscii to 0
   End If
End Sub
```

This makes ZodiacAnimal an array of the animals. Then using the Mod function, I get the right index of the array.

Answer (score 2):

also, it's way more propper to use

> vbKeyReturn

instead of the number 13, because not all the keyboards the ENTER would be 13.

so the proper way would be:

```
If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
```

(Please Rate my answer, thanks!)